# How to split a string in different words

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I want to split the string: `"3quartos2suítes3banheiros126m²"`

in this format using python:

```
3 quartos


2 suítes

3 banheiros    

126m²
```

Is there a built-in function i can use? How can I do this?

Comment: you can use python regex to do so : https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), specifically `re.findall()`

```
s = "3quartos2suítes3banheiros126m²"
matches = re.findall(r"[\d,]+[^\d]+", s)
```

gives a list containing:

```
['3quartos', '2suítes', '3banheiros', '126m²']
```

Regex explanation ([Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uwtlbw/2)):

```
[\d,]+        : Match a digit, or a comma one or more times
      [^\d]+  : Match a non-digit one or more times
```

Then, add a space after the digits using `re.sub()`:

```
result = []
for m in matches:
    result.append(re.sub(r"([\d,]+)", r"\1 ", m))
```

which makes `result =`

```
['3 quartos', '2 suítes', '3 banheiros', '126 m²']
```

This adds a space between `126` and `m²`, but that can't be helped.

Explanation:

```
Pattern        :
 r"([\d,]+)"   : Match a digit or a comma one or more times, capture this match as a group

Replace with: 
r"\1 "      : The first captured group, followed by a space
```

Comment: @GuilhermeCelliFadel See my edit. Brackets `[  ]` makes regex match any of the characters specified in the brackets. So I just changed `\d+` to `[\d,]+`